# Fault Injection: Logging during functional tests

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, fault

I have a very small test case:

```
@pytest.mark.bar
def test_snapshot_missing_snapshot_capacity():

    fault.clear_settings()
    fault.load_settings("{0}/test/test_bar_snapshot_capacity_missing.json".format(constants.RECOVERY_DIR))
    backup_ts = bar_snapshot.create_backup(cloud_storage_driver, cloud_storage_driver_md, hydra_client)
    assert not backup_ts
```

where `test_bar_snapshot_capacity_missing.json` has:

```
{
  "snapshot_capacity_missing": true
}
```

Basically I have injected fault here.

Now my code which I am testing is:

```
if fault.is_fault("snapshot_capacity_missing"):
    log.error("One or more incomplete backup/s intended for deletion do not have snapshot capacity. \
               Skipping deleting incomplete backup altogether.")
    return None
```

I don't get log.error printed on console at all. Even if I add log.error before the statement it does not get printed. My test case pass though. Any special setting to be made so that log statements work for functional tests?

Comment: How did you declare `log`?

Comment: import logging;    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)